# Proving a partial sum is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Assume $a_n$>0 and lim($n^2a_n$) exists. I need to show that the sequence of partial sums of ($n^2a_n$) converges.

I know that ($n^2a_n$) is bounded and increasing. I can also show that its sequence of partial sums is increasing and bounded below. Where I'm stuck is how to show that the sequence of partial sums is bounded above and therefore convergent.

Comment: You probably mean that the sequence of partial sums of $(a_n)$ converges. The sequence of partial sums of $(n^2a_n)$ certainly need not, example $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be the limit of the sequence $(n^2a_n)$. Then there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n > N$,
$$|n^2a_n - L| < 1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad n^2a_n < 1 + L \quad \Rightarrow \quad a_n < \frac{1 + L}{n^2}.$$
By the comparison test, $\sum a_n$ converges. As Andre pointed out in the comments on the question, $\sum n^2a_n$ need not converge.